# Significance of the bed time mantra

Tags: mantras, hanuman, identification-request, garuda, bhima

One of the mantras, which we usually recite before going to bed is,

> Ramaskandam Hanomantham Vynatheyam Vrukodharam
>   Shayanesha Spatenithyam Dhuswapnam Thasyanashyathi

which is a prayer to Hanuman, Garuda and Bheema to prevent bad dreams.

My question is, why exactly do we pray these 3 gods in particular and which religious text it is mentioned in?

Comment: You only told "to prevent bad dreams". Now don't u think there is strong connection of ghosts, snakes and daemons with bad dreams. And Hanuman, Garuda and Bheema are slayers of them.. just one analogy not a strong point though :)

Comment: Yeah @YDS, even I was thinking along the same lines. It is crude enough to make the point, though. Let's see if any one knows the actual answer :)